# Why snapd install failed?nothing provides bash-completion needed by snapd-2.57.6-2.el8.x86_64

Tags: rhel, snap

I run command

```
yum install snapd
```

got

```
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:34 ago on Thu 16 Feb 2023 03:14:18 PM UTC.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides bash-completion needed by snapd-2.57.6-2.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
[root@rhel ~]# yum install snapd --skip-broken
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:45 ago on Thu 16 Feb 2023 03:14:18 PM UTC.
```

I checked uname

```
Linux rhel.localdomain 5.14.0-162.12.1.el9_1.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Dec 20 06:06:30 EST 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

why did the snapd install failed on rhel9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the system is looking for `bash-completion`. You can try to search for it in the repos: `yum search bash-completion` and, if it's there, install it with `# yum install bash-completion`.